# Possibility of using 2 different snitches in the Multiple Data Centers cluster in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We have a multiple data centers cluster spanning across our own network and AWS.

We are currently using GossipingPropertFileSnitch snitch across our network.

Is it possible to use GossipingPropertFileSnitch on datacenter in our private network and Ec2MultiRegionSnitch in AWS ?

Comment: What would be a use case for this? The snitch purpose it's to make Cassandra aware of the network topology and route the requests efficiently in the cluster and allows Cassandra to send replicas in the cluster based on those information. But if you have different snitches, the cluster will receive different information from the nodes and this for sure will lead to confusion.

Comment: @Horia Thank your for your commend, really we need to add a new data center in AWS and do not want to change our exist data center . for that we need to use different snitches .

Comment: You need to update your snitch in the existing DC, also and the perform a repair.

Comment: @Horia How i can update it to Ec2MultiRegionSnitch where our nodes live in the normal network ,NOT AWS, Do you mean i must move these nodes to the AWS environment ?

Comment: I would say that I'm not a big fan of mixing such things. My suggestion is to read more about the Ec2MultiRegionSnitch. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archSnitchEC2MultiRegion.html

Comment: @Horia thank you very much for your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can continue to use **GossipingPropertyFileSnitch** in the AWS cluster as well. Just remember to automate or setup proper values for dc and rack in "cassandra-rackdc.properties" on the AWS nodes (just like you did in your own datacenter nodes).

Ec2MultiRegionSnitch gets this information free for you. Its rack and DC aware. But bad part about it is that the discovery of the nodes mandates public ip/internet and then future communications happen through private ips.

In short GossipingPropertyFileSnitch continue to work great.